# Why does Sonar want a LocalDateTime marked transient when it's already serializable?

Tags: java, sonarqube

I've got a sonar plugin to Eclipse, and it's giving me a

`Make this value-based field transient so it is not included in the serialization of this class`

on a LocalDateTime object. What I do not get is, LocalDateTime is definitely serializable. Here's the class

```
 public final class LocalDateTime
        implements Temporal, TemporalAdjuster, ChronoLocalDateTime<LocalDate>, Serializable {
```

Anyone have any ideas? Do I just not understand what transient means? Normally I wouldn't pay much attention, but I'm weirdly able to serialize it in a Get request, but not deserialize it in a post request and I'm wondering if it's related to this.

Answer (score 2):

According to [**Sonarsource rules explorer**](https://rules.sonarsource.com/java/RSPEC-1948)  :

> Fields in a Serializable class must themselves be either Serializable
>   or transient even if the class is never explicitly serialized or
>   deserialized. For instance, under load, most J2EE application
>   frameworks flush objects to disk, and an allegedly Serializable object
>   with non-transient, non-serializable data members could cause program
>   crashes, and open the door to attackers. In general a Serializable
>   class is expected to fulfil its contract and not have an unexpected
>   behaviour when an instance is serialized.

However as you've said the `LocalDateTime` is serializable. This means that sometimes Sonar rules are not good (when using Hibernate with Objects that contains LocalDateTime which is Serializable).

**One** solution would be to use your own rules instead of Sonar default ones. **Another** one (this is a workaround more than a solution) would be to annotate your field with : **`@SuppressWarnings("squid:S3437")`**